# Print a row from a database

Tags: php, printing, row

I need to print a row from a database, i know how to print columns, but having a hard time printing rows. Can someone tell me how to?

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categorias ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<p>" . $categoria ['descricao'] . "</p>";
    }
?>
```

This is how im printing columns

Comment: "printing" and "row" are pretty meaningless unless you include a tag for the specific language you're using. Doing so helps make sure that the question gets to readers who are familiar with that language, rather than just hanging out here waiting for someone to notice it. :-)

Comment: One way is to print all your columns, like you are printing one column. You could use indices instead of column name example: $categoria[0] etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is don't use SELECT * in PHP, it's extremely prone to errors. If you explicitly list the columns in your select statement you can concatenate them into a table in PHP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use **print_r** to debug selected data.

Also look for [Mysql Fetch Row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Always Use **Google**

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tr><?php
while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<td>" . $categoria ['descricao'] . "</td>";} ?></tr></table>
```

I use a table, where while the array is true places the values cell by cell in a row, because the loop is working inside the `<tr> </tr>` creating a new `<td>` for every record.

Comment: Add at least one paragraph of text to that describing _why_ your code is a solution. (It's certainly not a straight drop-in for the questioner's code as presented.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM categorias ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while ($categoria = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<p>" . $categoria['descricao'] . "</p>";
}
}
?>
```